# Computing the Fourier series

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Find the Fourier Series of  $f(x)=\begin{cases} -3 & x \in(-5,0) \\ 3 & x \in(0, 5) \end{cases}$

I know that:
$$a_0=0$$$$a_n=0$$but when I try to $b_n$ I have

$$b_n=\frac{-6\cos \left(5n\right)+6}{n}$$

How can I interpret my Fourier series?

Can u Help me? :c

Comment: You should specify the interval (-5,5)? and the arguments for the sin series.  There should be a $\pi$ in there.  It should look like $sin(k\pi x)$ where $k=n/10$?